# «Так называемый»

Tags: грамматика

Объясните, когда слова после «так называемый» нужно закавычивать?

Answer (score 1):

Никогда. Кроме случаев, когда закавычивание необходимо по общему правилу (особое или переносное значение).

*Запомните также:

Не заключаются в кавычки слова, следующие за словосочетанием так называемый. Исключение составляют случаи, когда эти слова употреблены в необычном или ироническом значении.*
gramota.ru

И вот ещё, источник, правда, не столь авторитетный, но я готов подписаться.

*В этом выпуске рассмотрим правило, которое регламентирует употребление конструкции «так называемый».

Она встречается, как правило, там, где нужно указать на то, что некие слова или выражения используются в переносном смысле или же в не свойственном им контексте. То есть в общем случае оборот «так называемый» можно заменить союзами «как бы» или «как будто (бы)». Во всех этих случаях не требуется ни выделение конструкции запятыми, ни заключение последующего слова или словосочетания в кавычки.

Однако следует отметить, что, если далее в тексте они повторяются уже без оборота «так называемый», то кавычки нужны, чтобы подчеркнуть иной смысл слова. Среди всех их, должно быть в насмешку над богом и Христом, стоит также длинноволосый и в парчовой ризе так называемый священник. И «священник» этот тут же под виселицей, обращаясь к убиваемым, держа перед собой крест, призывает для чего-то имя Христа (Л. Толстой).

Вероятно, ошибочное выделение запятыми словосочетания «так называемый» обусловлено его сближением с не имеющей ничего общего с ним вводной фразой «так сказать», которая действительно обособляется на письме. Моя, так сказать, «жизнь». Моя так называемая жизнь.*

www.newslab.ru/blog/281268

~~~Добавлено.
Я подумал и решил, что мою и "Грамоты" оговорку про особое значение можно снять. Случай редчайший, хорошего примера я так и не сообразил. Это надо иметь ряд из трех значений одного слова, второе из которых переносное, а третье - переносное от переносного, никак иначе. Вот что-то подобное следующему. Большой сейф назвается "медведем" (отсюда - медвежатник). И если в некоей группе есть привычка называть "медведем" человека, у которого "всё как в сейфе", то постановка кавычек в обороте *так называемый "медведь"* уместна. Но это всё равно непонятно будет без дополнительных развернутых пояснейний, кого там в честь чего назвали. Так что всегда можно смело писать без кавычек, не заморачиваясь.